# Selenium C# create Class Methods with WaitForElementPresent & WaitForPageToLoad etc

Tags: c#, class, selenium-webdriver, methods

Up until now I have been using a straight forward technique to define my xpath and to call a selenium action to use the xpath. For example:

Code with the test script -

```
selenium.WaitForElementPresent(Menu.Home); 

selenium.Click(Menu.Home); 

selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(null);
```

Code in Method -

```
public class Menu

{

  public const string Home = "//ul[@class='menunavigation']/li/a[contains(text(),'Home')]";

}
```

... before continuing onto my next action.

But this is not good practice as I am unnecessarily duplicating code in my test scripts. So I want build my class methods containing the additional waits etc. so that my test script will simply contains the line:

`selenium.Click(Menu.Home);`

And my method will look somethong like this:

```
public static void Home(string xpath, object selenium)

{

  xpath = "//ul[@class='gts-ribbon']/li/a[contains(text(),'Home')]";
  selenium.WaitForElementPresent(xpath);

  "now perform the click command"

  selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(null);

}
```

But this does not work for me because my C# is not strong.
Can somebody help me fix my method. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
 public void ClickSave(Element element, IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            if (webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText(element.Text)).Enabled)
            {
                element.Click();
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps some

Comment: Doesn't it equal to `webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("text")).Click()`? Also you should mention about implicit waits, as well as about migrating from selenium RC to webdriver.

Comment: Using Thread.Sleep() is an option but i always try to keep that as a last resort. Also the code above is not the same as webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("text")).Click()
that will throw an error if the element is not enabled

Comment: There is no need to use Thread.Sleep(). Please, read this section: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference. Also I believe Benny Meade want to see error if element is not enabled. He want to wait till this element will be available for interactions. So these two methods are equal from that point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like this in library file.

```
public void isPresentClick(DefaultSelenium selObj,string locator)  
{  
   selenium.WaitForElementPresent(locator);
   selenium.Click(locator);
   selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(3000);
}
```

No call this function when u required in following manner.
create an object (obj) of library and use the function.

```
object obj = new library();
obj.isPresentClick(selenium,"Menu.Home")
```

This will call the function in the library and execute the steps specified in it.

The syntax may be wrong please check as i have made this in limited resource in notepad.

From my suggestion u should not use wait for page to load in that library function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the design I choose in the end:

In my test script I call a new selenium command:

> selenium.ClickAndWait(Menu.Home);

I have a new class called Extensions, within this I have a dedicated method called 'ClickAndWait':

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SelectAndWait(this ISelenium selenium, string locator)
    {
        selenium.WaitForElementPresent(locator);
        selenium.Select(locator);
    }
}
```

And I still have my dedicated Menu Class with my Home etc methods:

```
public class Menu
{
    public const string Home = "//ul[@class='menunavigation']/li/a[contains(text(),'Home')]";
}
```

Thanks for all your suggestions and guidance folks : )
Benny